# How to change ints in lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote a function to calculate the number of words of a particular length and write it on the console.

```
def count():
read_data = file.read()
list_count = list(map(lambda word: len(word), read_data.split()))
list_count.sort()
counted_words = collections.Counter(list_count)
for key, value in counted_words.items():
    print(f"there are: {value} words of length: [{key}].")
```

I don't know how I can turn it into a list to draw a graph using `matplotlib.pyplot`.

Comment: Your code won't run, your function is not indented, it is the first failure. Then file is not defined. And you can't turn `int` to `list`. But if you want to create an iterable with length n, just do `range(n)`.

Comment: you should have a look how to return values from a function. try to return the `dict` `counted_words`, then call the function and save the return value to a variable, Then you can plot `counted_words.keys()` as x, and `counted_words.values()` as y with matplotlib

Comment: @Thyebri I know that there is no code call and that the file is not defined, but I don't see the sense in putting all the code, which is about 200 lines long

Comment: You are supposed to at least give a bare minimum amount of code that we can actually copy paste into a console and run.

Answer (score 0):

you define an empty list , a boucle for and each iteration you use append to add the len of the word.
What values do you want on X and Y it's not clear

Edit :

You can use the following code

```
plt.plot(counted_words.keys(), counted_words.values(),label="your label")
plt.legend(loc="upper left")
plt.title("Your title")
plt.xlabel("Name for the X axes")
plt.ylabel("Name for the Y axes")
```

Comment: I would like to draw the graph using key and value. sorry, I forgot to write about that

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help. Write a function that takes a filename as its only argument and which returns a Counter. You can then iterate over the Counter and plot according to the values found.

```
from collections import Counter

def count(filename):
    counter = Counter()
    with open(filename) as infile:
        for line in map(str.strip, infile):
            for word in line.split():
                counter[len(word)] += 1
    return counter

for k, v in count('YourFilenameGoesHere').items():
    print(f'There are {v} words of length {k}')
```